# Apache Solr 4.1 works, 4.3 (same config!) throws 404

Tags: solr

I've configured a sample Apache Solr 4.1 installation using this [tutorial](http://www.arunchinnachamy.com/apache-solr-installation-and-configuration/). The sample `http://localhost:8090/solr` (changed the port in server.xml) worked and redirected me to `http://localhost:8090/solr/admin` with some output.
Now, I've upgraded to Solr 4.3 by stopping tomcat6, removing /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war and solr, replacing the solr.war with the new one. After starting tomcat6, /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr gets recreated.
However, `http://localhost:8090/solr` now throws a 404.

> HTTP Status 404 - /
>   type Status report
>   message /
>   description The requested resource () is not available.
>   Apache Tomcat/6.0.35

It is strange, that it shows no paths, but only when I try to reach something in /solr. When I type in something random, the paths show up correctly in the 404, so something seems to be done by tomcat, but it is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i ran into a similar problem, it has somthing to do with this: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_0/changes/Changes.html#4.3.0.upgrading_from_solr_4.2.0
"Slf4j/logging jars are no longer included in the Solr webapp."

you have to do the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415948/solr-4-3-tomcat6-ubuntu-installation-exception

in your case probably: copy all files from example/lib/ext/ to /var/lib/tomcat6/lib/ (lib most likely doesn't exist, so create it)

Comment: My god, why isn't this documented anywhere. Will test it, thanks!